# Behavior of top, right, bottom, left css values when using 'px' vs '%'

Tags: css, position, frontend, element, pixel

When using `top, right, bottom, left` `css` values, why am I able to use percentages sometimes, but other times I have to use pixels (`px`), or the `element` won't respond.

**For example (on a given element):**

`top: 25%` - doesn't respond

`top: 150px` - works

I usually will use percentages over pixels (`px`) to keep things responsive, but why do percentages (`%`) sometimes not work? In what scenarios do each work best? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the WC3 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#percentage-units) for *percentage units* (`<percentage>`<sup>([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage))</sup>):

> Percentage values are always relative to another value, for example a
>   length unit.

A *length unit* (`<length>`<sup>([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length))</sup>) is a CSS data type that represents a **distance value**, or a value defined in *relative* (`em`) or *absolute* (`px`) length units.

A *percentage unit* (`<percentage>`<sup>([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage))</sup>) is a CSS data type that represents a **percentage value**.

*Percentage units* (e.g: `top: 50%`) used on nested elements won't apply if the containing element has no *length unit* (e.g: `height: 200px`) value defined, since *percentage values are always relative to another value*.
This behaviour can be observed in the code snippet embedded below.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.fixed-height {
    height: 200px;
    background: #4cbd2f;
}

.auto-height {
    background: #d04f38;
}

.nested {
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
}

hr {
    border: 2px dashed #d4d4d4;
    margin: 25px 0px;
}

.fixed-height, .auto-height {
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<h3>Fixed Height</h3>
<h4><code>height: 200px</code></h4>
<div class="fixed-height">
  <div class="nested"><code>top: 50%</code></div>
</div>
<hr>
<h3>Auto Height</h3>
<h4><code>height: auto</code></h4>
<div class="auto-height">
  <div class="nested"><code>top: 50%</code></div>
</div>
```

Demonstrated in the code snippet above, *percentage values* will be dependent on *length values*. So although both nested elements have a `top` property of `50%` declared, only the element nested in the containing element with a `height` property explicitly defined with *length* values will result in the expected behaviour.

> **Note:** Although `<percentage>` values are also CSS dimensions, and are
>   usable in some of the same properties that accept `<length>` values,
>   they are not themselves `<length>` values.
>   [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

> **Note:** Only calculated values can be inherited. Thus, even if a
>   percentage value is used on the parent property, a real value (such as
>   a width in pixels for a `<length>` value) will be accessible on the
>   inherited property, not the percentage value.
>   [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.example {
    margin-top: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

This fixes the problem sometimes for me. You shall need to configure this to meet your needs obviously but by adding `display:inline-block` it usually fixes the problem.

Comment: thanks for the response...are you saying to use margin-top instead of top and sometimes percentages will work that way too? sometimes i feel like both dont work....i use `inline-block` when I am trying to position items next to eachother but ill try it when i run into this again.

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to create, so yes I am suggesting give it a try as it virtually does the same thing in some aspects.

Comment: i was just thinking about how this happens sometimes - its not in reference to specific code....just want to see if i can get some educated answers on the subject in general

Comment: I understand now, I am currently at work but when I get home I may be able to help more.